# convert irregular dates

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I got a list of irregular dates like this:

> Thu, 29 Sep 2005 17:52:45 GMT
>
> Wed, 17 Aug 2005 21:21:08 +0200
>
> Wed, 17 Aug 2005 20:08:22 +0200
>
> Mon, 15 Aug 2005 21:44:07 +0200
>
> Sun, 24 Jul 2005 21:47:09 +0200
>
> Sun, 24 Jul 2005 12:37:46 -0700 (PDT)
>
> Sun, 24 Jul 2005 21:37:51 +0200
>
> Mon, 11 Jul 2005 21:19:38 +0200
>
> Mon, 11 Jul 2005 21:19:02 +0200
>
> Mon, 11 Jul 2005 20:43:08 +0200 (CEST)
>
> 13 Nov 2006 14:06:20 +0000

How and can i convert them to DateTime or just Time with either JodaTime or the default java date class? (joda time prefered).

Comment: Are they `String`s or `Date`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of those are following a certain [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). Prepare a [chain (chain of responsibility pattern)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) of predefined DateFormat handlers and pass the date String's you have into the chain. Let the appropriate handler parse the date and return the Date for you.

NOTE: This is assuming that the dates you have posted are available for you in string format. If you  have a java.util.Date object then I believe what you are seeing is a display time format.

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know buddy how to do it with jodatime, but what u can do is use

String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

Answer (score 0):

Pangea i was to tired when i read your message, i wanted to post the solution and i read it back and now i realize i could have done it a lot easier with trying and on a null return or something try a different pattern.

Anyway this was the hard way solution:

```
String[] days = {
  "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"
};
String[] months = {
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
};
String[] years = {
  "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011"
};


// ORDER IS VERRY IMPORTANT!! ( MEST must be before EST for example)
String[] timesZones = {
  "BST", "CET", "CEST", "CST", "CDT", "EDT", "GMT+00:00", "GMT", "IST", "MEST", "EST", "MET", "MDT", "PST", "PDT", "SAST", "UTC", "UT", "W. Europe Standard Time", "West-Europa (zomertijd)"
};

DateTime handleDate(String date) {

  String origDate = date;

  String timeZone = "";
  String year = "";
  String month = "";
  String day = "";
  int hours = 0;
  int minutes = 0;
  int seconds = 0;

  // is it valid?
  date = trim(date);
  if (date.equals("")) {
    return null;
  }

  // first delete the comma that comes mostly after the day
  date = date.replaceAll(",", "");

  // remove the day
  for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    if (date.contains(days[i])) {
      date = date.replace(days[i], "");
      break;
    }
  }


  // if(date.contains("23:27:17")) println(date);

  for (int i = 0; i < timesZones.length; i++) {
    // first check with '(' and ')'
    String target = "("+timesZones[i]+")";

    if (date.contains(target)) {      
      timeZone = timesZones[i];
      date = date.replace(target, "");
      break;
    }

    // if not found check without '(' and ')'
    if (date.contains(timesZones[i])) {      
      timeZone = timesZones[i];
      date = date.replace(timesZones[i], "");
      break;
    }
  }

  // get the month
  for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    if (date.contains(months[i])) {
      month = months[i].toLowerCase(); // !must be lowercase
      // must be dutch on my pc
      if(month.equals("oct")) month = "okt";
      if(month.equals("may")) month = "mei";
      if(month.equals("mar")) month = "mrt";

      date = date.replace(months[i], "");
      break;
    }
  }

  // get the year
  for (int i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    if (date.contains(years[i])) {
      year = years[i];
      date = date.replace(years[i], "");
      break;
    }
  }

  // get the time
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(date);
  if (m.find()) {
     // also fix the time, 00 is not allowed
    hours = int(m.group(1));
    minutes = int(m.group(2));
    seconds = int(m.group(3));

    date = date.replaceAll("(\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)", "");
  }

  // get the time difference
  date = date.replace("+-", "+0"); // bug fix where data is incorrect ( 16 Sep 2007 23:27:17 +-200)

  p = Pattern.compile("[+|-]*(\\d\\d)\\d\\d");
  m = p.matcher(date);
  if (m.find()) {
    int timeDifferenceH = int(m.group(1));

    date = date.replaceAll("([+|-]*\\d\\d\\d\\d)", "");
  }

  date = " "+date; // bug fix

  // get the day
  for (int i = 31; i >= 1; i--) {
    // first check for the ones that contains 2 digits (like 07)
    String d = nf(i, 2);
    if (date.contains(d)) {
      day = nf(i, 2);
      date = date.replace(d, "");
      break;
    }

    // check for 1 digit
    d = ""+i;
    if (date.contains(d)) {
      day = nf(i, 2);
      date = date.replace(d, "");
      break;
    }
  }


  // there should be nothing left except white space
  date = date.replace(" ", "");
  if (date.equals("") == false) {
    println("handleDate: problem with input\n"+date);
    println(origDate+"\n");
    println(year);
    println(month);
    println(day);
  }


  String cleanDate = day+"/"+month+"/"+year+" "+nf(hours, 2)+":"+nf(minutes, 2)+":"+nf(seconds, 2);

  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  try {
      DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(cleanDate);
      return dt;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      println("handleDate: Problem with formatting: "+cleanDate);
    }

  return null;  
}
```